# useLayoutEffect fires off before useState is set

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

so here is the code the problem is the request is sent before the page count can be set I added a timeout function but to no avail when I reload it the request works properly and sends the pageCount but on the first load it sends it alone it doesn't say undefined or null its just sends Student/get

Edit: This happens only in the final build it works in development specifically on chrome it works fine on Microsoft edge

```
     export function Home() {
     const [pageCount, setPageCount] = useState(0);
      const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);
      const [first, setFirst] = useState(true);
      const [last, setLast] = useState(true);
      const navigate = useNavigate();

      useLayoutEffect(() => {
      setTimeout(() => {
      axios
      .get(constants.baseUrl + `Student/get/${pageCount}`, {
       headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem("token")}`,
      },
    })
    .then((res) => {
      setCourses(res.data.content);
      setLast(res.data.last);
      setFirst(res.data.first);
    });
  }, 300);
 }, [pageCount]);
```

Comment: The initial `pageCount` state value is `0` and should be available on the initial render cycle. I don't see where it's ever undefined.

Comment: Here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/uselayouteffect-fires-off-before-usestate-is-set-bhs2bl) demo showing the initial `pageCount` state value is available in the `useLayoutEffect` hook callback.

Comment: I forgot to mention it works in development its the final build that act like this

Answer (score 0):

Check if `pageCount` exists in `useLayoutEffect()` and if not, use the default value.

Something like:

```
const PAGE_COUNT_DEFAULT = 0
const [pageCount, setPageCount] = setState(PAGE_COUNT_DEFAULT);

...


useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if(pageCount) axios.get(...${pageCount})...
    else axios.get(...${PAGE_COUNT_DEFAULT})...
})
```